# Fill input box which has ghost text in VB.net webbrowser control

Tags: vb.net, input, innertext

In VB.net, I am trying to automatically fill a website input box which has some ghost text.

(Namely, here is the area with those boxes: here is the site that has them: http://calgary.kijiji.ca/c-buy-and-sell-cameras-camcorders-Leica-M8-2-in-near-mint-condition-W0QQAdIdZ525074644QQfeaturedAdZtrue - the boxes on the right)

The problem is: if I try to fill it like I fill boxes with no ghost text (element.InnerText = "whatever"), the entered text is perceived as ghost text, so if the user clicks on the box after the text was entered, the text disappears. - http://prntscr.com/1srjcu

Code:

```
For Each element As HtmlElement In frmMain.wb1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
            If element.Name = "FromEmailAddress" Then
                Dim i = 0
                dim strLine = "sample text"
                        element.InnerText = strLine
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
```

I tried using element.Focus() prior to element.InnerText, but that doesn't help. I know that ghost text is done with javascript, so can I implement some javascript in the code to change the inputbox value like that?

Any suggestions appreciated. Let me know if you need more info.

Thanks!

Comment: please post your code

Comment: [code] For Each element As HtmlElement In frmMain.wb1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
            If element.Name = "FromEmailAddress" Then
                Dim i = 0
                For Each strLine As String In TextBox1.Text.Split(vbNewLine)
                    If i = 2 Then
                        element.InnerText = strLine
                    End If
                    i = i + 1
                Next
            End If
        Next
[/code]

Here is the code that is supposed to change the inputbox text. It has some extra lines which parse the text to enter - they are irrelevant

Comment: please format it and post as a part of the question

Comment: EDIT: I solved this by changing the class of the element, so the ghost text was converted to regular, and it become easy to modify with element.innertext 

element.SetAttribute("className", "") - the line that made this work

PS. For something even easier, use element.InvokeMember("click") ;)